# Can I iterate through a NodeList using for-each in Java?

Tags: java, xml, dom

I want to iterate through a `NodeList` using a for-each loop in Java. I have it working with a for loop and a do-while loop but not for-each.

```
NodeList nList = dom.getElementsByTagName("year");
do {
    Element ele = (Element) nList.item(i);
    list.add(ele.getElementsByTagName("MonthId").item(0).getTextContent());
    i++;
} while (i < nList.getLength());

NodeList nList = dom.getElementsByTagName("year");

for (int i = 0; i < nList.getLength(); i++) {
    Element ele = (Element) nList.item(i);
    list.add(ele.getElementsByTagName("MonthId").item(0).getTextContent());
}
```

Comment: You cannot use foreach loop for NodeList as it does not implement Iterable interface. Only option you have it to use the for or while loop using nodeList.getLength.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/NodeList.html

Comment: While this is tangential to the question you're asking, I would shy away from using the w3c stuff from the Java standard library. IMO it's a hot mess and there are much better XML parsing libraries out there.

Comment: +Jazzepi I know it's old topic but which XML parsing library are you suggesting ? NB The fact that this w3c library doesn't offer a simple and generic Iterator is a "detail" but look like one more argument against this stuff (even if the choice of a library could be more complex than this point).

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The workaround for this problem is straight-forward, and, thankfully you have to implements it only once.

```
import java.util.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public final class XmlUtil {
  private XmlUtil(){}

  public static List<Node> asList(NodeList n) {
    return n.getLength()==0?
      Collections.<Node>emptyList(): new NodeListWrapper(n);
  }
  static final class NodeListWrapper extends AbstractList<Node>
  implements RandomAccess {
    private final NodeList list;
    NodeListWrapper(NodeList l) {
      list=l;
    }
    public Node get(int index) {
      return list.item(index);
    }
    public int size() {
      return list.getLength();
    }
  }
}
```

Once you have added this utility class to your project and added a `static` `import` for the `XmlUtil.asList` method to your source code you can use it like this:

```
for(Node n: asList(dom.getElementsByTagName("year"))) {
  …
}
```

Answer (score 23):

I know it is late to the party, but...
Since Java-8 you can write [@RayHulha's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19589231/can-i-iterate-through-a-nodelist-using-for-each-in-java/32781802#32781802) even more concisely by using lambda expression (for creating a new [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html)) and default method (for [`Iterator.remove`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--)):

```
public static Iterable<Node> iterable(final NodeList nodeList) {
    return () -> new Iterator<Node>() {

        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return index < nodeList.getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Node next() {
            if (!hasNext())
                throw new NoSuchElementException();
            return nodeList.item(index++); 
        }
    };
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
NodeList nodeList = ...;
for (Node node : iterable(nodeList)) {
    // ....
}
```

or equivalently like this:

```
NodeList nodeList = ...;
iterable(nodeList).forEach(node -> {
    // ....
});
```

Comment: clean and simple! Thank you.. +1 for showing how to use it.

Comment: Or `return () -> IntStream.range(0, nodeList.getLength()) .mapToObj(nodeList::item) .iterator();`

Answer (score 12):

```
public static Iterable<Node> iterable(final NodeList n) {
  return new Iterable<Node>() {

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {

      return new Iterator<Node>() {

        int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
          return index < n.getLength();
        }

        @Override
        public Node next() {
          if (hasNext()) {
            return n.item(index++);
          } else {
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
          }  
        }

        @Override
        public void remove() {
          throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }
      };
    }
  };
}
```

Comment: From here: https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2012/07/13/turn-org-w3c-dom-nodelist-into-iterable/

Comment: downvoting because there is no descripton of the code

Answer (score 9):

Adding the happy little kotlin version for sience:

```
fun NodeList.forEach(action: (Node) -> Unit) {
    (0 until this.length)
            .asSequence()
            .map { this.item(it) }
            .forEach { action(it) }
}
```

One can then use it with `nodeList.forEach { do_something_awesome() }`

Comment: You can do the same thing with `NamedNodeMap` for `attributes` of a `Node`

Comment: I don't know Kotlin (some Scala) but don't you need to put `it` in the example usage?

Comment: Is really hard to search the docs for `it` but it's a shorthand for a local variables, instead of writing `map { element -> this.item(element) }` one can simply write `map { this.item(it) }`

Answer (score 5):

As `NodeList` is just an interface, you could create a class which would implement both `NodeList` and `Iterable`, in order to iterate through it.

Answer (score 5):

One can use the Java8 stream to iterate the NodeList.

```
NodeList filterList = source.getChildNodes();

IntStream.range(0, filterList.getLength()).boxed().map(filterList::item).forEach(node -> {


});
```

Comment: Nice! But `boxed().map` can be replaced with `mapToObj` for better efficiency.

Answer (score 4):

There are ready to use or copypaste iterator implementations in [`org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators.NodeListIterator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/jacoco/org.apache.commons.collections4.iterators/NodeListIterator.java.html) and `com.sun.xml.internal.ws.util.xml.NodeListIterator`.

Answer (score 3):

`NodeList` does not implement `Iterable`, so you cannot use it with the enhanced `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

If the current DOM element is removed (via JavaScript) while iterating a NodeList (created from getElementsByTagName() and maybe others), the element will disappear from the NodeList. This makes correct iteration of the NodeList more tricky.

```
public class IteratableNodeList implements Iterable<Node> {
    final NodeList nodeList;
    public IteratableNodeList(final NodeList _nodeList) {
        nodeList = _nodeList;
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<Node> iterator() {
        return new Iterator<Node>() {
            private int index = -1;
            private Node lastNode = null;
            private boolean isCurrentReplaced() {
                return lastNode != null && index < nodeList.getLength() &&
                       lastNode != nodeList.item(index);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                return index + 1 < nodeList.getLength() || isCurrentReplaced();
            }

            @Override
            public Node next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    if (isCurrentReplaced()) {
                        //  It got removed by a change in the DOM.
                        lastNode = nodeList.item(index);
                    } else {
                        lastNode = nodeList.item(++index);
                    }
                    return lastNode;
                } else {
                    throw new NoSuchElementException();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void remove() {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        };
    }

    public Stream<Node> stream() {
        Spliterator<Node> spliterator =
            Spliterators.spliterator(iterator(), nodeList.getLength(), 0);
        return StreamSupport.stream(spliterator, false);
    }
}
```

Then use it like this:
`new IteratableNodeList(doc.getElementsByTagName(elementType)).
stream().filter(...)`

Or:
`new IteratableNodeList(doc.getElementsByTagName(elementType)).forEach(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The validated solution is very useful, but here I share an improved solution based on the valid one, this helps you iterate as well, but easy to use, and secure:

```
public class XMLHelper {
    private XMLHelper() { }

    public static List<Node> getChildNodes(NodeList l) {
        List<Node> children = Collections.<Node>emptyList();
        if (l != null && l.getLength() > 0) {
            if (l.item(0) != null && l.item(0).hasChildNodes()) {
                children = new NodeListWrapper(l.item(0).getChildNodes());
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    public static List<Node> getChildNodes(Node n) {
        List<Node> children = Collections.<Node>emptyList();
        if (n != null && n.hasChildNodes()) {
            NodeList l = n.getChildNodes();
            if (l != null && l.getLength() > 0) {
                children = new NodeListWrapper(l);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }

    private static final class NodeListWrapper extends AbstractList<Node> implements RandomAccess {
        private final NodeList list;
        NodeListWrapper(NodeList l) {
            list = l;
        }
        public Node get(int index) {
            return list.item(index);
        }
        public int size() {
            return list.getLength();
        }
    }
```

}

Usage:

```
 for (Node inner : XMLHelper.getChildNodes(node)) { ... }
```

Thanks @Holger.

Answer (score 0):

I want to thank @Calin for the inspiration with the Kotlin code, but I want to go a little bit further and to be able to filter NodeList content by type and subclass in one line

```kotlin
fun <T : Node> NodeList.forEach(clazz : KClass<T>, vararg nodeType: Short, action: (T) -> Unit) {
    (0 until this.length).asSequence().map { this.item(it) }
        .filter { nodeType.isEmpty() || nodeType.contains(it.nodeType)  }
        .filter { clazz.isInstance(it) }.map { clazz.java.cast(it) }
        .forEach { action(it) }
}

// original variant without any filtering, used for node's attributes

fun NamedNodeMap.forEach(action: (Node) -> Unit) {
    (0 until this.length).asSequence().map { this.item(it) }
        .forEach { action(it) }
}
```

Usage example:

```kotlin
xmlDoc.childNodes.forEach(Element::class, Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    println("tag ${it.tagName} with attributes: ") // 'it' is an Element here
    it.attributes.forEach { attr -> println("${attr.nodeName} - ${attr.nodeValue}")}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly an answer to the question but may still be helpful for others ending up here:

I also looked for a way to iterate over `NodeList` but I usually prefer streams of loops. So I ended up with this method:

```java
public static Stream<Node> streamElementsByTagName(Document dom, String tagName) {
  var nodes = dom.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
  return nodes == null
      ? Stream.empty()
      : IntStream.range(0, nodes.getLength()).mapToObj(nodes::item);
}
```