# Java 8 Stream API: get all nodes after specific Node

Tags: java, dom, java-8, java-stream

I have `org.w3c.dom.NodeList` with 5 nodes. Nodes ids generated by `UUID.randomUUID();`

Dom structure:

```
<section id="3" prefix="s1">
  <paragraph id="value3">
  ...
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph id="value4">
  ...
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph id="value5">
  ...
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph id="value6">
  ...
  </paragraph>
  <paragraph id="value7">
  ...
  </paragraph>
</section>
```

I need to get all nodes after node with attribute id="value5". So result should contain nodes with id=value6 and id=value7.

I created `Stream<Element>`:

```
NodeList children = element.getChildNodes();
Stream<Element> elementStream = IntStream.range(0, children.getLength())
                                         .mapToObj(children::item)
                                         .filter(Element.class::isInstance)
                                         .map(Element.class::cast);
```

So, Could I somehow to do this with Java 8 Stream API?

Comment: Try to filter them by `attribute > 5`

Comment: @AndriiAbramov, id is generated value. I can't to compare them.

Comment: In jdk-9 you could do something like this: `.dropWhile(i -> i != 5).skip(1)`

Comment: @Eugene, Thank you. Unfortunately we use jdk-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, the DOM API doesn’t play well with other APIs. I have provided a useful lightweight `List` wrapper in [this earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19591302/2711488).

With this, you could simply do:

```
List<Node> list = XmlUtil.asList(element.getChildNodes());
list = list.subList(
    list.indexOf(element.getOwnerDocument().getElementById("value5"))+1, list.size());

Stream<Element> stream = list.stream()
    .filter(Element.class::isInstance).map(Element.class::cast);
```

or

```
List<Node> list = XmlUtil.asList(element.getChildNodes());
Stream<Element> stream = IntStream.range(
        list.indexOf(element.getOwnerDocument().getElementById("value5"))+1, list.size())
    .mapToObj(list::get).filter(Element.class::isInstance).map(Element.class::cast);
```

Comment: An alternative direction would be `Stream.iterate(element.getOwnerDocument().getElementById( "value5"), Node::getNextSibling)`, which unfortunately suffers from the lack of an ability to end the stream at `null`, which would bring us back to Java 9, where these issues are fixed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but we decided to use XPath for this task.

Answer (score 4):

Your question is quiet confusing. But if you need to get only nodes after Element with specific attribute and they are ordered, you can try to filter Elements by their attributes:

```
public List<Element> filterElements(NodeList items, int attributeStart){

    List<Element> result = IntStream.range(0, items.getLength())
            .mapToObj(children::item)
            .filter(Element.class::isInstance)
            .map(Element.class::cast)
            .filter(e -> Integer.parseInt(e.getAttribute("id")) > attributeStart)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    return result;

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But unfortunately id value generated by random uuid: UUID.randomUUID(); And I can't compare them.

Comment: @AndrewNepogoda and now my answer seems to be stupid :(
Is there any order rule for UUID? Could we sort them?

Comment: Sorry for  unclear question. Our ids just random values and we can't sort them:(

Answer (score 1):

We decided to use `XPath` for this task. It looks much better:

```
    private static final String EXPRESSION_TEMPLATE = "//*[@%s='%s']";
    private static final String ID_ATTR = "id";
    // some code here
    @Override
    public NodeList lookupSiblingsAfterId(Element aRootElement, String id) {
        try {
            if (null == id) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid id parameter");
            }
            return (NodeList)xpath.newXPath().evaluate(String.format(EXPRESSION_TEMPLATE, ID_ATTR, id) + "[last()]/following-sibling::*", aRootElement, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        } catch (XPathExpressionException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Can't evaluate XPath expression", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```

I hope it would be helpful for somebody.